# Token alway not valid

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data, jwt

In a spring boot reactive project, with r2dbc I try to add security with jwt

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    private final ReactiveUserDetailsServiceImpl userService;

    private final TokenProvider jwtTokenUtil;

    private final JWTReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    ...

    @PostMapping(value="authorize")
    public Mono<JWTToken> authorize(LoginUser loginVM) {
        if (loginVM ==null || loginVM.getUsername().isEmpty() || loginVM.getPassword().isEmpty()) {
            return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Bad request"));
        }

        Authentication authenticationToken =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginVM.getUsername(), loginVM.getPassword());

        Mono<Authentication> authentication = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
        authentication.doOnError(throwable -> {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad crendentials");
        });
        ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(authenticationToken);

        return authentication.map(auth -> {
            String jwt = jwtTokenUtil.createToken(auth);
            return new JWTToken(jwt);
        });
    }
}

@Service
public class ReactiveUserDetailsServiceImpl implements ReactiveUserDetailsService, UserService {

    @Autowired
    private  UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public Mono<UserDetails> findByUsername(String username) {

        return userRepository.findByUsername(username)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new BadCredentialsException(String.format("User %s not found in database", username))))
                .map(this::createSpringSecurityUser);

    }

    private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User createSpringSecurityUser(User user) {

        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();

        SimpleGrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole());

        grantedAuthorities.add(grantedAuthority);

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
    }

    public Flux<User> findAll(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

}   


@Component
public class TokenProvider {

    private final long validityInMilliseconds = 3600000; // 1h

    private static final String SALT_KEY = "123";

    private String secretKey;

    private final Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();

    private static final String AUTHORITIES_KEY = "auth";

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(TokenProvider.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.secretKey = encoder.encodeToString(SALT_KEY.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    }

    public String createToken(Authentication authentication) {

        String authorities = authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

        long now = (new Date()).getTime();
        Date validity = new Date(now + this.validityInMilliseconds);

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(authentication.getName())
                .claim(AUTHORITIES_KEY, authorities)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secretKey)
                .setExpiration(validity)
                .compact();

    }

    public Authentication getAuthentication(String token) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(token) || !validateToken(token)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid token");
        }

        Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(secretKey)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();

        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities
                = Arrays.stream(claims.get(AUTHORITIES_KEY).toString().split(","))
                        .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

        User principal = new User(claims.getSubject(), "", authorities);

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, token, authorities);

    }

    private boolean validateToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKey).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            logger.info("Invalid JWT signature.");
            logger.trace("Invalid JWT signature trace: {}", e);
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            logger.info("Invalid JWT token.");
            logger.trace("Invalid JWT token trace: {}", e);
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            logger.info("Expired JWT token.");
            logger.trace("Expired JWT token trace: {}", e);
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            logger.info("Unsupported JWT token.");
            logger.trace("Unsupported JWT token trace: {}", e);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.info("JWT token compact of handler are invalid.");
            logger.trace("JWT token compact of handler are invalid trace: {}", e);
        }
        return false;
    }

}

public class JWTReactiveAuthenticationManager implements ReactiveAuthenticationManager {

    private final ReactiveUserDetailsServiceImpl userService;

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(JWTReactiveAuthenticationManager.class);

    public JWTReactiveAuthenticationManager(final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, final ReactiveUserDetailsServiceImpl userService) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication) {

        if (authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            return Mono.just(authentication);
        }

        return Mono.just(authentication)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(this::raiseBadCredentials))
                .cast(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class)
                .flatMap(this::authenticateToken)
                .publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                .onErrorResume(e -> raiseBadCredentials())
                .filter(u -> passwordEncoder.matches((String) authentication.getCredentials(), u.getPassword()))
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(this::raiseBadCredentials))
                .map(u -> new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authentication.getPrincipal(), authentication.getCredentials(), u.getAuthorities()));

    }

    private <T> Mono<T> raiseBadCredentials() {
        return Mono.error(new BadCredentialsException("Invalid Credentials"));
    }

    private Mono<UserDetails> authenticateToken(final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken) {
        String username = authenticationToken.getName();

        logger.info("checking authentication for user " + username);

        //todo change, it's not reactive
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            logger.info("authenticated user " + username + ", setting security context");
            return userService.findByUsername(username);
        }

        return null;
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SpringSecurityWebFluxConfig {

    private ReactiveUserDetailsServiceImpl userService;

    private TokenProvider tokenUtil;

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
        "/resources/**",
        "/webjars/**",
        "/authorize/**",
        "/favicon.ico",};

    public SpringSecurityWebFluxConfig(TokenProvider tokenUtil, ReactiveUserDetailsServiceImpl userService) {
        this.tokenUtil = tokenUtil;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http, UnauthorizedAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint) {

        http.httpBasic().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .logout().disable();

        http
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
                .and()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)
                    .permitAll()
                .pathMatchers("/users")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                .addFilterAt(webFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHORIZATION)
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                .anyExchange().authenticated();

        return http.build();

    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationWebFilter webFilter() {
        AuthenticationWebFilter authenticationWebFilter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(repositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager());
        authenticationWebFilter.setAuthenticationConverter(new TokenAuthenticationConverter(tokenUtil));
        authenticationWebFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationMatcher(new JWTHeadersExchangeMatcher());
        authenticationWebFilter.setSecurityContextRepository(new WebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository());
        return authenticationWebFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JWTReactiveAuthenticationManager repositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager() {
        JWTReactiveAuthenticationManager repositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager = new JWTReactiveAuthenticationManager(passwordEncoder(), userService);
        return repositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I try to connect with curl with this line

> curl -X POST localhost:8889/authorize -u admin:123

I see in debug then validateToken receive: WRtaW46cGVybWFjb24=

> Error trapped is: MalformedJwtException

Don't understand why

If i try to call directly /users (not supposed to add security) i get

> curl -X GET  http://localhost:8889/users

I get

> Error: SEVERITY_LOCALIZED=ERROR, SEVERITY_NON_LOCALIZED=ERROR,
>   CODE=42601, MESSAGE=syntax error at or near ".", POSITION=12,
>   FILE=scan.l, LINE=1128, ROUTINE=scanner_yyerror

Comment: `validateToken receive: WRtaW46cGVybWFjb24=`  so you mean this is the token you received? This is not a JWT!

Comment: User enter username, and password, in the server when i debug, in getAuthentication method, token string received is WRtaW46cGVybWFjb24

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spring Security, but the token you get is not a JWT, but `validateToken` expects a JWT, no surprise that it fails.